# Twitter Bootstrap and Angular.js- Dynamically Add Tabs and Tab Content but its not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I'm using Bootstrap tabs with an Angular ng-repeat.
But when I clicked on any tab it's not opened

```html
<div id="content">
    <div class="wrap full">
<div ng-init="names = [{name:'one'}, {name:'two'}, {name:'three'}, {name:'four'}, {name:'five'}]">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li ng-repeat="name in names" ng-class="{active: $index == 0}">
      <a href="#tab{{$index + 1}}" data-toggle="tab">Week {{$index + 1}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="tab{{$index + 1}}" ng-repeat="name in names" >
      <p>{{$index + 1}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you paste the markup of some of the dynamically added tabs? If the href on the anchors don't match the IDs of the tabs, the click won't work as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out UI Bootstrap for AngularJS: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

It includes directives for all Bootstrap UI elements.

Placing and registering these in your app will allow you to define tabs like this: `<tab></tab>`

Check the docs for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap tabs require javascript to load them

```
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
});
```

Each tab needs to be activated individually

Comment: He's using AngularJS, so the minimal JQuery solution won't work here.

Comment: In that case he should be using angular bootstrap http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 0):

Provide the id to the ul element and then call tab methos in script file. 
**Demo**
http://plnkr.co/edit/w0URah6KiiXrSwaRCxcJ?p=preview
 HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="2.3.2" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.1.5" data-semver="1.1.5" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.0.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap@2.3.2" data-semver="2.3.2" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="appController">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div id="content">
      <div class="wrap full">
        <div ng-init="names = [{name:'one'}, {name:'two'}, {name:'three'}, {name:'four'}, {name:'five'}]">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="mytab">
            <li ng-repeat="name in names">
              <a href="#tab{{$index + 1}}" data-toggle="tab">Week {{$index + 1}}</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="tab{{$index + 1}}" ng-repeat="name in names">
              <p>{{$index + 1}}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Script file

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('appController', function($scope){
   $('#mytab').tab('show');
  });
```

Comment: Angular zen tries to reduce usage of JQuery as much as possible. Good rule: If you're writing a JQuery statement in your controller, write a directive instead.

Comment: Angular easily accept the JQuery syntax, so i don't thing there is any issue while using jquery syntax.  Angular contains jQlite(lite version of jQuery iself.)So i don't think so there is something wrong in my solution.